# How does LIC_FILES_CHKSUM work for one line match in Yocto?

Tags: md5, licensing, yocto

For ROS recipes, recipes contain a license extracted from an XML and line is indicated in the recipe:
For example, for [XMLRCPP](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros/blob/master/recipes-ros/ros-comm/xmlrpcpp_1.11.21.bb):

```
LICENSE = "LGPL-2.1"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://package.xml;beginline=11;endline=11;md5=184dd1523b9a109aead3fbbe0b4262e0"
```

But [Ar-track-alvar](https://github.com/sniekum/ar_track_alvar/blob/19e6f390a757dcbc304c33a847bb2811f11e6d9b/package.xml) has the same license name but a different MD5:

```
LICENSE = "LGPL-2.1"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://package.xml;beginline=10;endline=10;md5=061abe8dc89f326789675967c8760541"
```

Hence, how is this MD5 calculated if the strings are the same?

EDIT: @jku explained the reason and how it works. The simple explanation is that the second package.xml has 2 whitespaces at start

Comment: As far as i know **beginline** and **endline** are used to define which lines within a file are to be used for creating the md5sum.
Both recipes deliver their own, but probably equal package.xml. If they are exact identical, the difference is in **beginline** and **endline** being different. Maybe you check that and tell us, whether that made the different md5sum

Comment: It was a good idea but it does not interfer because some other recipes have different lines with BSD licenses and all have `d566ef916e9dedc494f5f793a6690ba5` as MD5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the checksums are different, then the strings are not the same. The difference could be just whitespace or different copyright years.

The purpose of LIC_FILES_CHECKSUM isn't to ensure that the license really is what it claims to be (because that's not practically possible). Instead it's used to make sure the license does not change without the recipe maintainer noticing when the recipe version is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the details, but how can you explain this particular case then?

Comment: So, I found out one of the strings had indeed 2 spaces empty before. I expected it to be filtered out but it's not. Anyway, thanks for the explanation